# Не выскакивает клавиатура на версии ниже 5.0

Tags: android, android-edittext, клавиатура, android-inputmethodmanager

В активити выскакивает `AlertDialog`, в котором размещены два спинера и `EditText`. При нажатии на `EditText` должна выскочить клавиатура `numberDecimal`. Так вот при запуске в API не ниже 21 всё работает, то при запуске, скажем, в API 19 клавиатура просто не выскакивает, сколько ни нажимай. Вот объект в `layout`:

```
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editDisplayTextAmount"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/enter_amount"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    tools:text="Введите сумму" />
```

Вот инициализация `EditText` со слушателем:

```
    final EditText editDisplayText = (EditText) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.editDisplayTextAmount);

    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
    editDisplayText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            Log.d("keyCode", String.valueOf(keyCode));
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN &&
                    (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                String s = editDisplayText.getText().toString();
                Log.d("enter numbers", s);
                if (s.length() != 0) amount = Double.parseDouble(s);
                if (amount <= 0) amount = 1;
                alertDialog.cancel();
                setRate();
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS, 0);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Позже я даже специально добавил в код

```
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```

чтобы явно вызвать клавиатуру. Этот код уже вставлен в код выше. При этом в API 21+ она выскакивает (и убирается), а в API, выпущенных до эпохи исторического материализма, по-прежнему не хочет, сколько в неё ни тыкай.

В чём проблема? В `numberDecimal`? В чём-то ещё? Как исправить, чтобы работало и выскакивала именно нужная клавиатура?

UPD. Поменял `numberDecimal` на `text` — воз и ныне там.

UPD 2. В эмуляторе Galaxy Nexus API 19 почему-то ни одна клавиатура не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте вызвать вот так

```
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager =
(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInputFromWindow(editDisplayText.getApplicationWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```